# Retrieve picklist and its dependent field value email template

Tags: email-template, picklist, dependent-picklist

I'm newbie in salesforce and my first task is to create an email template with some conditionals.

Then, this what I have:

- Object called Service Request,
- **Picklist field** called Sub Type 1 and
- 5 **Field dependencies** picklist related to it, Sub Type 2

In my template I have the 2 following needs:

**1. FIRST:** *Reason field*: Based one Sub Type 1 field, show me Sub type 2 field

So i've done the following attempts, but didn't work:

```
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Service_Request__c.SR_Sub_Type_1__c,"Entrega(Delivery)"),
     Service_Request__c.Delivery__c)}
```

Where `Delivery__c` is one of the dependent field picklist. Also, i have 5 `IF's` nested

---

**2. SECOND:** *Classification field*: I must retrieve, respectively, the Sub Type 1 and Sub type 2 and concatenate them, but i can't even get success in the first task...

Could please help figure out what i'm doing wrong? Please let me know if I could express myself in good way...

Thank you,
Susane

Comment: For #1 - Your IF statement is missing an else condition.  With 5 nested IFs, you need to debug this step-by-step by adding each additional nested if statement one at a time to see where it is breaking.  For #2 - you might want to consider formula fields on the service_request__c object to move some of the logic out of the email template. This can greatly improve clarity and make doing concatenation easier

Comment: Here is the official word from SFDC support: "While formulas do sometimes work in templates we don't officially support them. We have no documentation on them we almost always recommend the customer uses a Visualforce template if they have this requirement.
If they don't want to go that route they can always create a formula field on the object that does this, and just merge that into the email template. This can cause a large amount of fields to pile up, so it isn't always recommended." - link :https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpJRAA0

Comment: However, it does look like you can try different stuff and see what works. Apparently, the text encoding can make a difference, length of output text and all sorts of other stuff. You'll likely have more luck if you keep the formula short. Perhaps try a CASE statement in this instance.

Comment: Oh, and your if statement looks fine, btw.

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks for observing that... here goes a question...Do I need to always inform an else condition like " " or NULL even when I dont need that? And my nested IF's do not work, because this simple and only IF clause does not work, and I couldn't find the error out there... my eyes are tired and can't find the reason of not working... even putting an else statement.

Comment: @CaspNZ thanks again for sharing an idea article. Just voted! It's really important to know that people are facing the same kind of matter as you.. thanks again... As you mentioned that my statement above is ok, should It work, right? Could  we say that email template is kind of unstable? I saw some posts from people saying that certain code worked for them, but when I try the exactly same code it does not work for me... don't know what happened... :(

Comment: For the **2 option**, Is this concatenate statement right? `{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Service_Request__c.SR_Sub_Type_1__c,"Entrega"),Service_Request__c.SR_Sub_Type_1__c = " " + Service_Request__c.Delivery__c, NULL)}` ?

Comment: 1) The doc says that `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`; 2) Concatenation in formulas is done with the `&` operator, not the `+` operator